# C# and mysql connection error

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, ip, server

I've tried to connect mysql with c# in visual studio, but it returns exception: "Unable to connect to any specified mysql hosts."

```
            Debug.WriteLine("metodA LOad");
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"../../Resources\konfiguracja.conf");

        /*string mojePolaczenie =
        "SERVER=" + lines[0] + ";" +
        "DATABASE=" + lines[1] + ";" +
        "UID=" + lines[2] + ";" +
        "PASSWORD=" + lines[3] + ";";*/

        string mojePolaczenie = "Server=ip;Port=3306;Database=db;Uid=login;Password=pass;";

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(mojePolaczenie);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM linie";

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Otworzyłem połączenie");
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while(reader.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(reader["nrlinii"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Why doesn't it work?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: conn.Open() throws the exception. I moved this line from try/catch below MysqlConnection conn declaration.

Comment: _server=ip_ this means that your MySql database server is located on an external server from your local network? If yes, do you have the necessary permissions to access it remotely?

Comment: The mysql db is located on ext server. I've already checked connection and everything is ok.